# Authentication at my web site using other credentials

Tags: authentication

Suppose there are 2 web site: `example.com` I don't own and `example2.com` I own. I want to extend the functionality of `example.com` somehow.

`example.com` doesn't have any API. I want the users of `example.com` to be able to login at `example2.com` using their logins and passwords of `example.com`. However, since `example.com` doesn't have any API, it is not easy to do, perhaps, it is even impossible.

No doubt, no one would agree to enter their credentials of `example.com` at `example2.com` due to many obvious reasons.

So, is there any way to authenticate the users of `example.com` at `example2.com` **(or somewhere else)** using their original credentials?

Comment: I don't think so. That would mean you could steal their credentials for example.com.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you need one (or more) of the following things to do single sign-on:

- A shared root-level domain, e.g. all sites are subdomains of example.com. They can share a cookie this way, assuming both sites understand the format.
- A shared credential database (SQL, LDAP, etc.) with both sites knowing how to validate the credentials (e.g. type of hashing used on the passwords).
- A trust system such as [WS-Federation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Federation) supported by all participating sites.
- An authentication API supported by at least one of the participating sites (such as [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Federation)).

From your rather vague description, it sounds like you lack any of the above, so the answer is no, you can't do this - not without tricking the users in an essentially criminal fashion.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you need to ask the owner of `example.com` to share with you his authentication method with you (if it's a friend of you, or a partner, otherwise it's very unlikely he accept to share something as sensitive with you).

Assuming the owner of `example.com` is using a MySQL database with a specific table for users and password **and** that he is willing to help you with this, here is a example of what to do:

- he needs to create for you a remote MySQL user with read access to the users table from example2.com (e.g.: `auth%[ip.of.example2.com]`);
- he also needs to permit remote connection to his MySQL database (firewall –preferably with ip filtering- and my.cnf);
- then, he has to provide to you the way he store the password (hash algorithm, salt method…);
- at this point, when a user try to login to `example2.com`, you just have to create a MySQL connection to his server, and check the credentials…

Even if all this is really moot, I hope this will help a little.